# Bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the open interval (0, 1)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the open interval (0, 1)

No ideas,if someone could point me towards the example it would help. Is this in some way related to space filling curves ?

Comment: $\mathbb R^2 \cong \mathbb R\cong (0,1)$